# Python gribapi function not yet implemented

Tags: python, grib-api

I'm using [GRIB_API](https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/GRIB/Python) to parse my grib2 files. I tried [Iterator.py](https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/GRIB/iterator.py) but when I run my python script I got this error :

```
GRIB_API ERROR   :  jpeg support not enabled. Please rerun configure with the --with-jasper or --with-openjpeg option.
GRIB_API ERROR   :  unable to get codedValues as double array (Function not yet implemented)
GRIB_API ERROR   :  unable to get values as double array (Function not yet implemented)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iterator.py", line 43, in main
    example()
  File "iterator.py", line 16, in example
    iterid = grib_iterator_new(gid,0)
  File "/program/gribapi.py", line 70, in modified
    return _func_(**kw)
  File "/program/gribapi.py", line 495, in grib_iterator_new
    GRIB_CHECK(err)
  File "/program/gribapi.py", line 70, in modified
    return _func_(**kw)
  File "/program/gribapi.py", line 143, in GRIB_CHECK
    raise GribInternalError(errid)
GribInternalError: Function not yet implemented
```

How can I fix this error ?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but it might be helpful... https://stackoverflow.com/a/44246941/175793